# Scroll is going down when I use sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have these js files:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js
Functions.js
```

and this html:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

in `Functions.js`, I have:

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        cancel: ".fixed"
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

in my jsfiddle, it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/ZV6sF/1/

but in my project, when I try to choose `li` and order it after another `li`, the scroll is going down till the bottom of the page.

is there someone that has an idea why it's happening?

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the containment option for the sortable, so that the list elements can only be dragged within their container.
For example:

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        cancel: ".fixed",
        containment: "#sortable"
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: @PertaStone, thank you but it doesn't work.. the page is still going to the bottom when I drag an li..

Comment: @AlonShmiel, it works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox, with no unwanted scrolling.